# Cannot set the system to automatically suspend and then hibernat when closing the lid

Tags: suspend, power-management, systemd, hibernate

When I close the lid, the system goes to "suspend" mode, but then the hibernation never happens.

I know that suspend and then hibernation works ok, because the following command makes it work as it should (suspend, and after some time hibernate):

```
sudo /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend-then-hibernate
```

The problem is that it doesn't do the needed sequence when closing the lid. It's like systemd, when closing the lid, goes to "suspend" and not to "suspend-then-hibernate", but don't know how/where to fix it.

With the current config, the relevant part (I think) of syslog is:

```
Feb 15 20:46:52 antorcha systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 15 20:46:52 antorcha systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Feb 15 20:46:52 antorcha systemd-sleep[10863]: Suspending system...
Feb 15 20:59:19 antorcha systemd-sleep[10863]: System resumed.
```

(which indicates that it goes to "suspend" and not "suspend-then-hibernate".

This is my sleep.conf:

```
[Sleep]
HibernateDelaySec=20
HibernateState=disk

#AllowHibernation=yes
#AllowHybridSleep=yes
#AllowSuspend=yes
#AllowSuspendThenHibernate=yes
#HibernateMode=platform shutdown
#HybridSleepMode=suspend platform shutdown
#HybridSleepState=disk
#SuspendMode=suspend-then-hibernate
#SuspendState=mem standby freeze
```

(the time to wait set to 20 seconds just for debugging)

And this is my logind.conf (all commented out):

```
[Login]
HandleLidSwitch=suspend-then-hibernate
HandleSuspendKey=suspend-then-hibernate

#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillUserProcesses=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#NAutoVTs=6
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#RemoveIPC=yes
#ReserveVT=6
#RuntimeDirectoryInodes=400k
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#SessionsMax=8192
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
```

This is my system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy

$ uname -a
Linux antorcha 5.8.0-40-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 15 11:05:36 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You may want to remove some of the `#` characters in your `sleep.conf` file, as those are commenting out some of the lines you need … 

Comment: The commented out lines are the defaults of the system, according to `systemd` config.

Comment: I just tried uncommenting HandleLidSwitch (and HandleSuspendKey, JIC), because of the link you sent me before. But still not working

Comment: I also added a small snippet of `syslog`.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service suspend-then-hibernate already exists in Ubuntu but for whatever reason the system suspend is still being called. This could be due to a GRUB configuration issue (upon startup) or symbolic links. Turn suspend into suspend-then-hibernate in /etc/systemd/logind.conf then uncomment the lines modified. 
Next make the symbolic links necessary to call suspend-then-hibernate.service to systemd-service while deleting the systemd-service link.
                                                       
`sudo rm -f /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service`

 `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-suspend-then-hibernate.service /etc/systemd/system/systemd-suspend.service`

Next find the UUID of the Linux Swap drive by:
`sudo blkid /dev/sda'x'` (*x is the partition of SWAP*)     
Copy the UUID and open the /etc/default/grub (nano as root) and add or update the following to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** entry so it looks like the following >>>>>
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash resume=UUID=5c03967e-b9fe-4a2e-8501–05002aa51dd6"` (or whatever the **UUID** is)

Now run the following commands to update grub with the new changes 
`sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

`sudo update-grub` 
(reboot afterwards)
 Here are some useful sources and links to study possible issues. 
 [2019 Article on how to correctly configure suspend-then-hibernate](https://medium.com/@gayanper/make-ubuntu-sleep-like-windows-4761a91f62c2)
  [Documentation on sleep-then-hibernate and how the state is saved in RAM in Ubuntu 20.10](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/man5/systemd-sleep.conf.5.html)

Comment: Thanks! Changing the service one for the other did the trick. (FTR, I already had GRUB configured ok, hibernation itself was working properly).